# Laptop boots twice to start

Tags: boot, laptop

I have an ASUS N552VX laptop with Nvidia GeForce GTX 950. It's battery died. It's CMOS battery is not working too. Whenever i shut it down and try to boot again. It powers up then shuts down by itself after 3-4 seconds and then boots again and works fine. It didn't use to be like this. Why is this so? Please help thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes that kind of thing is normal.  If you can, replace the CMOS battery, otherwise the motherboard won't keep the current time

See this site for more information: http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-3498025/computer-booting.html